# Calling method of different activity via interface leads to error: system service not available before onCreate

Tags: java, android-studio, interface

I have an AlarmManager in Activity 'PopShowAlarms'. This is a List of alarms,  which the user can activate and deactivate. If he does so, the AlarmManager creates a new Alarm. Obviously the user also needs to be able to add alarms. He can do this in the second activity 'PopAddAlarm'. To make this newly created alarm, 'PopAddAlarm' calls a method of 'PopShowAlarms'. There the new data should be converted into an alarm instantly. This always leads to the error, that I can't use SystemServices before onCreate.

First I tried to call the method simply by making a new object of the class

```
    Class class = new Class();
    class.method();
```

This resulted in the error: can't call SystemServieces before onCreate

Now I've been told, that I have to use an Interface to do so, but I still get the same error. Because I'm new to interfaces, I think that's where the mistake might be.
Here is my code:

Activity 'PopShowAlarms':

```
public class PopShowAlarms extends AppCompatActivity implements interfaceForwardAlarm {

...


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_show_alarms);

        ...

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwitchChange(int position, boolean switchOnOff) {

        // when user activates the alarm, this code is triggered

            if (switchOnOff) {
                RecyclerViewElement currentElement = savedList.get(position);
                String time = currentElement.getmAlarmTime();

                // deleted methods that convert String 'time' to a calendar object

                setAlarm(Calendar);
            }
        }
    });

...

public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    int count = getCount();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, count, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

...


// this is the implemented method from the interface
@Override
public void forwardAlarm(Context context, String alarmTime, String activeDays, String motivation, String music) {
    setCalendar(alarmTime);
}
```

}

Second Activity: 'PopUpAdd

```
public class PopupAdd extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_popupadd);

    ...

    imageViewAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int hour = numberPickerHour.getValue();
            int minute = numberPickerMin.getValue();
            String activeTime = Integer.toString(hour)+":"+Integer.toString(minute);

        ...

        // the chosen alarm Time is forwarded to the activity 'Pop Show Alarms'
        PopShowAlarms popShowAlarms = new PopShowAlarms();
            popShowAlarms.forwardAlarm(context, activeTime, activeDays, "motivation", "music");


            finish();


    }
```

The Mentioned interface:

```
public interface interfaceForwardAlarm {
void forwardAlarm(Context context, String alarmTime, String activeDays, 
String motivation, String music);
}
```

I'd be greatful for any help. I often struggle with this problem. (Calling methods from different activities) I hope this is at least the right approach

Comment: "I hope this is at least the right approach" – Unfortunately, it's not. You should never try to directly access members of other Activities like that, and using an `interface` isn't going to help. The system must handle `Activity` instantiation; otherwise, it is not initialized correctly, and you get errors like that. The simplest, proper way to share data between Activities is probably with `startActivityForResult()`/`onActivityResult()` – https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465.

Comment: @Mike I'm aware of this possibillity, but to my knowledge this also opens the UI of the other activity. Is there a possibility to do this in the background?

Comment: Sorry my bad. The UI doesn't change if you use startActivityForResult(). Thank you :)